# live or recorded

Tags: screenwriting

I'm writing an interview a la 60 minutes or Behind the Music, where the interviewer show footage of the subject's homelife. I'm not sure if I'm supposed to indicate that the "behind the scenes" footage used should be written as Recorded in the slugline. For example:

INT. SOUND CONTROL ROOM - DAY

Amanda Jones interviews Vince Smith.

```
                                Amanda
                       Let's talk about your green lifestyle.
```

They laugh.

```
                               Vince
                        Why not Amanda, lets.
                                                            CUT TO:
```

INT. GREEN HOUSE - DAY (RECORDED)
Vince shows Amanda around his futuristic green house.

I'm curious if that's the correct formatting for footage that isn't considered "live". Does it matter that I indicate it in the slugline or not?

Comment: Karen why did you create a duplicate of your other question, which is still open?

Comment: It is very similar but not 100% the same. This asks about formatting while the other asks about wording. Could be clearer but different nevertheless, I feel.